# Как подготовить к работе БД PosgreSQL + TypeORM при первом деплое на продакшен-подобную среду?

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

B [официальной документации NestJS](https://learn.nestjs.com/p/fundamentals) рассмотрена конфигурация БД для режима локальной разработки:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql', // для PosgreSQL настройки аналочные
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: 'root',
      database: 'test',
      entities: [],
      synchronize: true,
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

при этом сказано, что на продакшене устанавливать `synchronize` значение `true` небезопасно.

Хорошо, а что делать-то? Если просто оставить это значение в положении `false`, то при попытке обращения к базе данных произойдёт ошибка:

```
ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] relation "XXX" does not exist
```

Короткий ответ на вопрос я знаю: "миграции". Но тут есть некоторые детали, без знания которых это волшебное слово сдвига с мёртвой точки не даст.

Во-первых: означает ли это, что нужно в приведённой выше конфигурации прописывать условную конструкцию, согласно которой запускать миграцию нужно на всех режимах кроме локальной разработки?

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      // ...
      synchronize: __IS_LOCAL_DEVELOPMENT_MODE__,
      migrations: [
         ...__IS_LOCAL_DEVELOPMENT_MODE__ ? [] : [ CreateDataBaseMigration ]
      ]
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Если да, то я так чувствую, что по мере добавления новых миграцией все эти условия будут становиться всё сложнее и сложнее.

Второе: если нам всё равно придётся создавать базу данных с помощью миграции, то зачем нам `synchronize: true`? Что отложить написание этой миграции на потом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, в режиме продакшена не рекомендуется использовать опцию `synchronize: true`, так как это может привести к потере данных. Вместо этого рекомендуется использовать миграции базы данных.

Вы можете использовать условную конструкцию, как вы предложили, чтобы запускать миграции только в режиме продакшена. В приведенном примере, если переменная `__IS_LOCAL_DEVELOPMENT_MODE__` равна `true`, то миграции не будут запущены, в противном случае будут запущены.

Но рекомендуется использовать какой-то инструмент для миграций, например TypeORM migrations, или любой другой, который поддерживает вашу БД. Это позволит вам легко отслеживать изменения в базе данных и откатывать их, если необходимо.